# Wordpress Nav Walker Anchor only in li

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I have a custom wordpress theme and would like my menu to be a little different than Wordpress standards like this:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">About Me</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I only manage to remove the `<li>` in my walker class but can't manage to move the links inside the 1 li tag.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

EDIT :
This was achieved now by using wp_get_nav_menu_items.

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to do that, but I think it would probably just be easiest to call [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) and skip creating a walker. Walkers only really come in handy if you have a sub-nav, which I can't tell from your code if one exists or not.

Comment: Excuse my mind. I completely forgot about this function. This worked.